# how do i script hunpos through text files?

Tags: linux, bash, nlp, nltk

my purpose is to parse several text files using the POS parser HunPos http://code.google.com/p/hunpos/wiki/UserManualI

is there a way to bash script hunpos through a bunch of text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical mechanisms look like:

```
for f in glob; do command $f ; done
```

I often run commands like: `for f in *; do echo -n "$f " ; cat $f ; done` to see the contents of all the files in a directory. (Especially nice with `/proc/sys/kernel/`-style directories, where all the files have very short contents.)

or

```
find . -type f -exec command {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 command parameters
```

Something like `find . -type f -exec file {} \;` or `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file` (only works if the command accepts multiple filenames during input).

Of course, if the program accepts multiple filename arguments (like `cat` or `more` or similar Unix shell tools) and all the files are in a single directory, you can very easily run: `cat *` (show contents of all files in the directory) or `cat *.*` (show contents of all files with a period in the filename).

If you frequently want "all files in all [sub]*directories", the zsh [`**/`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#l140) option can be handy: `ls -l **/*.c` would show you `foo/bar/baz.c` and `/blort/bleet/boop.c` at once. Neat tool, but I usually don't mind writing the `find` command equivalent, I just don't need it that often. (And zsh isn't installed everywhere, so relying on its features could be frustrating in the future.)

Comment: A few things to note 1) terminating `find`'s -exec option with `\;` will cause it to call `command` once for each input file found, i.e. only a single input. 2) posix conforming versions of `find` can have -exec terminated with `+` rather than `\;` to be functionally identical to your `xargs` version.  3) Bash 4.X introduced the `shopt -s globstar` shell option to add recursive globbing via `**` just like zsh.

Comment: the problem with hunpos tagger is that it doesnt work as a one liner #bash command. the "./hunpos-tagger en_wsj.model" command opens a new line for stdio but not reading the text file. is there someway to get it to read my text files?

Comment: @SiegeX, awesome, never knew of `find`'s `+` option, and I hadn't realized newer `bash` stole the cool feature from `zsh`. It didn't work when I tried it in my shell, so I assumed they didn't like it for some reason. :) Thanks!

Comment: @2er0, I'd try running a command like this first: `./hunpos-tagger en_wsj.model < input_filename`. If that works, then try: `cat input*filenames* | ./hunpos-tagger en_wsj.model`. You may wish to read about [shell redirection](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/01/inputoutput-redirection-made-simple-in.html) and [shell pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to learn how to feed almost any file into most Unix programs.

Comment: thanks, i guess that's shelling and piping is the only way to use command based hunpostagger thanks.